# SwiftUI context menu doesn't show the element under an if

Tags: swift, swiftui

As you can see in the photos for some reason the context menu doesn't render the PinnedMessageView

I tried to remove the the modifier or use a true as condition for the if but it doesn't seem to change anything.

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el6Kk.png)

[context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgtuq.png)

MessageView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var persistenceController
    var message: Message
    
    @Binding var refresh: Bool
    @Binding var pinnedMessage: Message?
    
    @State var swipeDelta: CGFloat = 0
    @State var messageSize: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    if(message.pinnedMessage != nil) {
                        PinnedMessageView(message: message.pinnedMessage!, width: 50, maxWidth: Float(messageSize.width), isUser: message.isUser)
                    }
                    Text(message.text!)
                        .frame(minWidth: 50)
                        .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 10)
                        .padding(.top, (message.pinnedMessage != nil) ? 0 : 10)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        .background(message.isUser ? .blue : Color(UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 229/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.8)))
                        .cornerRadius(10, corners: [.topRight, .topLeft, (message.isUser) ? .bottomLeft : .bottomRight])
                        .cornerRadius(0, corners: [(message.isUser) ? .bottomRight : .bottomLeft])
                        .overlay(time, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                        .foregroundColor(message.isUser ? .white : .black)
                        .saveSize(in: $messageSize)
                }
                .padding([.horizontal, .top], (message.pinnedMessage != nil) ? 4 : 0)
                .background(
                    (message.pinnedMessage != nil)
                    ? (message.isUser ? .blue : Color(UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 229/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.8)))
                    : Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, opacity: 0)
                )
                .cornerRadius(10, corners: [.topRight, .topLeft, (message.isUser) ? .bottomLeft : .bottomRight])
                .cornerRadius(0, corners: [(message.isUser) ? .bottomRight : .bottomLeft])
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    if(!message.saved) {
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                message.saved = true
                                try? persistenceController.save()
                                refresh.toggle()
                            },
                            label: { Label("Save", systemImage: "star")}
                        )
                    } else {
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                message.saved = false
                                try? persistenceController.save()
                                refresh.toggle()
                            },
                            label: { Label("Unsave", systemImage: "star.slash")}
                        )
                    }
                    
                    Button(
                        role: .destructive,
                        action: {
                            persistenceController.delete(message)
                            try? persistenceController.save()
                            refresh.toggle()
                        },
                        label:  { Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash") }
                    )
                })
                .offset(x: swipeDelta, y: 0)
                .animation(.spring(), value: swipeDelta)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged {
                            if ($0.location.x > 0) {
                                swipeDelta = min($0.location.x, 100)
                            } else {
                                swipeDelta = max($0.location.x, -100)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .onEnded { endedGesture in
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                swipeDelta = .zero
                            }
                            
                            if((endedGesture.location.x - endedGesture.startLocation.x) > 0) {
                                pinMessage()
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 250, alignment: message.isUser ? .trailing : .leading)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: message.isUser ? .trailing : .leading)
    }
    
    private var time: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            if(message.saved) {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 8))
            }
            Text(dateString())
                .font(.system(size: 10))
            if (message.isUser) {
                if(message.confirmed) {
                    Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 8))
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "location.slash")
                        .font(.system(size: 8))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
        .padding(.trailing, 5)
    }
    
    private func pinMessage() {
        pinnedMessage = message
    }
    
    private func dateString() -> String {
        var formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return formatter.string(from: message.date!)
    }
}

struct MessageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    var message1 = Message()
    
    init() {
        message1.confirmed = true;
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

PinnedMessageView

```
import SwiftUI

struct PinnedMessageView: View {
    var message: Message
    var width: Float
    var maxWidth: Float = 300
    var isUser: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(message.text!)
            .foregroundColor(
                isUser
                ? Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, opacity: 0.0035)
                : Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.35)
            )
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .italic()
            .padding(10)
            .frame(minWidth: CGFloat(width), maxWidth: CGFloat(maxWidth))
            .background(
                isUser
                ? Color(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, opacity: 0.0005)
                : Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.05)
            )
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

struct PinnedMessageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text("not available")
    }
}
```

I would add a more minimal example but I tried to replicate this issue and I'm not able to do it, so I don't understand what caused it.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add your `Message` type code to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: [Edit] your question and clarify your issue. What do your images show? What is not working?